# How to write autocall function in VUE js for live website?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a function in Vue js who can auto-call on the live website at a particular time interval, which works is to check the database(google firebase cloud-firestore) collection/object.
This function does not depend on any events like (at-click, on-change, on-load, etc ).
It's completely independent, it's just called at a particular time interval

Comment: Sounds like a fairly clear use-case. What problem do you have while implementing it? Can you edit the question to show what you already tried, and where you got stuck?

Comment: please try cron job in server

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timer in your Vue object in `main.js`

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {},
    created: function() {
        setInterval(() => {
          // call your API to check the database stuff
        }, 1000)
    }
});
```

But better approach is to **create a dynamically scheduled background job in backend**.